# iOS Facebook login not working after upgrade to 5

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

I updated my facebook SDK to the latest version (5) with below pods

```
pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
```

Here is my updated facebook login function

```
    let loginManager = LoginManager()
    loginManager.loginBehavior = .browser  //.native is not supported in new version

    loginManager.logIn(permissions: ["publicProfile", "userFriends", "email"], from: self) { (login, error) in
        if let e = error {
            self.showAlertForError(title: "", msg: e.localizedDescription)
            return
        }

        if let l = login {
            if l.declinedPermissions.contains("user_friends") || l.declinedPermissions.contains("email") {
                SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
                self.showAlertForError(title: "facebook_permission_required_text".localized(), msg: "facebook_permission_allow_text".localized())
                return
            }

            GraphRequest(graphPath: "/me", parameters: ["fields" : "id, email, first_name, last_name"])
                .start(completionHandler:  { (connection, result, error) in
                    guard let result = result as? NSDictionary,
                        let email = result["email"] as? String,
                        let first_name = result["first_name"] as? String,
                        let last_name = result["last_name"] as? String,
                        let user_id_fb = result["id"]  as? String else {
                            SVProgressHUD.dismiss()

                    }
                })

        }
    }
```

When trying to login getting this error.

[image: Login error]

Comment: If you are using swift you can use `FacebookLogin` pod instead of `FBSDKLoginKit`

Comment: @Mahendra tried, same error

Comment: Try with one version lower. May the latest version has some issue. It was already happened earlier with the Facebook login sdk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still send requests in the same way as you do with the existing `iOS SDK`

The current approach to `Graph API` requests uses a `custom type-safe API` for the requests. This allows you to reason about the types of your `graph API` requests more accurately, and provides a `clean API` for consuming this data.

```swift
let connection = GraphRequestConnection()

    @IBAction private func loginWithReadPermissions() {
        let loginManager = LoginManager()
        loginManager.logIn(
            permissions: [.publicProfile, .userFriends, .email],
            viewController: self
        ) { result in
            self.loginManagerDidComplete(result)
        }
    }

   func loginManagerDidComplete(_ result: LoginResult) {
        switch result {
        case .cancelled:
            self.showAlertForError(
                title: "Login Cancelled",
                message: "User cancelled login."
            )

        case .failed(let error):
            self.showAlertForError(
                title: "Login Fail",
                message: "Login failed with error \(error)"
            )

        case .success(let grantedPermissions, _, _):
            self.showAlertForError(
                title: "Login Success",
                message: "Login succeeded with granted permissions: \(grantedPermissions)"
            )
 connection.add(GraphRequest(graphPath: "/me", parameters: ["fields" : "id, email, first_name, last_name"])) { httpResponse, result, error   in
    if error != nil {
        NSLog(error.debugDescription)
        return
    }
       guard let result = result as? NSDictionary,
           let email = result["email"] as? String,
           let first_name = result["first_name"] as? String,
           let last_name = result["last_name"] as? String,
           let user_id_fb = result["id"]  as? String else {
               SVProgressHUD.dismiss()

            }
          }
    connection.start()
        }
    }
```